# How to arrange a string to display

Tags: excel, vba, string

How can I generate a string using vba that lets certain characters line up. As an example, lets say the strings generated over two rows are as follows:

```
"96 x $219.00 = $21,024.00"
"-8 x 45.00 = -360.00"
```

I want spaces added to the left of the rightmost number to have the "=" signs line up.
I also want spaces added to the left of the middle number to have the "x" character line up.
These strings are generated from a vba function.

I'm restricted to using Times-Roman Size 8 (company requirement, no negotiating)
Also, the string is to be right justified, in case someone is concerned.

After trying to extract the character width using Columns.ColumnWidth and comparing the widths of repeating a character say 10 and then 11 times (I tried other sets of numbers than these), then building a function to break down a string into characters and sum them, padding as described, the characters still don't line up. There should be a way to do this in vba. There are too many tables to fix by hand. Previous posting discussing just padding characters, fail to address how they are displayed.

Comment: Optionally, could you split this string using Text-to-Columns feature and the `=` as delimiter, and then insert a new column between that contains the `=`. This way you can use column alignments to align your text. I would also HIGHLY suggest that whichever route you go, that you use a monospace font. A non-monospace font will only align by coincidence and luck.

Comment: You can't use a non-monospace font and achieve the desired effect. Set the font to Courier New (it was the default monospace font back when Times New Roman was the default in MS-Office!), or Consolas, and check again if your padding is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Aligning text by inserting spaces is a terrible idea (word processing 101). Plus it is modifying the data, and as a user I would complain if I enter `a=b` into a cell and all of a sudden it is      `a=b`.

Aligning text for a non-proportional font by adding spaces is impossible. You can only have a "best attempt" which approximately aligns them.

There is no build-in function in Excel (or VBA) to achieve this.

So, I did the following just for fun. Take it or leave it.

**(1)** There is no build in function for the text width of a string in VBA. If you google around, you can find different attempts, but one suggestion is rather easy to understand: Put a label on a user form, format it to the font you are interested in (eg Times New Roman, 8pt, Non-Bold, Non-Italic) and set properties `AutoSize = True` and `.WordWrap = False`.

When assigning any text to this label, it changes its size and you can read the width of it. Now this doesn't return the exact width of the text as the label uses some extra pixels to the left and right - but for our purposes we can ignore that.

So create a userform and put a label on it. Don't worry, you don't need to show the form, the resize of the label will be done even if the form is not displayed.

Now put the following code into a regular module:

```
Function GetTextWidth(s As String) As Double
    Static f As UserForm1
    If f Is Nothing Then Set f = New UserForm1
    With f.Label1
        .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Font.Size = 8
        .Font.Italic = False
        .Font.Bold = False
        .AutoSize = True
        .WordWrap = False
        .Caption = s
        GetTextWidth = .Width
    End With
End Function
```

**(2)**
Now we need to loop over all data (all cells of your range), split the text into the part left of the equation sign and the part right of it using `split`, calculate the word length for the left part and remember the length of the widest string.

**(3)**
Now we loop another time over all the data, again split the text, take the left part and add spaces to the left until the width is larger (or equal) than the max length  we just calculated. If we reach the point, we check if this "nearer" to the max length or if we should go for one space left.

Code for Step 2 and 3:

```
Sub alignTextrange(r As Range, Optional alignChar As String = "=")
    Const SpacesAroundAlignChar = 1
    
    ' First: Find widest string to the left of alignChar
    Dim maxWidth As Double, currWidth As Double, prevWidth As Double
    Dim leftWord As String
    Dim cell As Range, tokens() As String
    
    For Each cell In r
        tokens = Split(cell.Value, alignChar)
        If UBound(tokens) = 1 Then      ' 2 pieces (like a = b)
            leftWord = Trim(tokens(0))
            currWidth = GetTextWidth(leftWord)
            If currWidth > maxWidth Then maxWidth = currWidth
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print "Max: " & maxWidth
    If maxWidth = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' And now: Align all other cells to the one with the widest left string
    For Each cell In r
        tokens = Split(cell.Value, alignChar)
        If UBound(tokens) = 1 Then      ' 2 pieces (like a = b)
            leftWord = Trim(tokens(0))
            prevWidth = GetTextWidth(leftWord)
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 1 To 100
                currWidth = GetTextWidth(Space(i) & leftWord)
                Dim spacesNeeded As Long
                If currWidth >= maxWidth Then
                    If maxWidth - prevWidth < currWidth - maxWidth Then
                        spacesNeeded = i - 1
                    Else
                        spacesNeeded = i
                    End If
                    cell = Space(spacesNeeded) & leftWord _
                         & Space(SpacesAroundAlignChar) & alignChar _
                         & Space(SpacesAroundAlignChar) & Trim(tokens(1))
                    Exit For
                End If
                prevWidth = currWidth
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Of course there is room for improvement, like reading/writing the data into an array or to precalculate the width of several spaces, this should only show the rabbit hole you need to go down.

If this is not good enough then your only option is to go for spaces with a smaller font, but then it gets much more complicated. Or convince your bossed to get rid of this ugly font (or look for a new job).

(*alignted* is obviously a typo, too lazy to correct in my sheet and redo the screenshots).